# AngularJS factory method not found in Rails project

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently working on this  AngularJS Tutorial: Learn to Build Modern Web Apps with Angular and Rails  https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/ which I think is a great resource showing how to build Rails Web Apps with AngularJS.

So far, I've completed over two thirds of the tutorial successfully, but now I'm facing some issues with factory services. When I hit the post button to create new post, I get the following error:

[image]

**Error message**

```
angular.js?body=1:11608 TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.addPost (http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/home/mainCtrl.js?body=1:23:24)
```

It points to the code below in **mainCtrl.js** file:

```
                posts.create({
                    title: $scope.title,
                    link: $scope.link,
                });
```

the entire **mainCtrl.js** file:

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts', function ($scope, posts) {

        $scope.test = 'Hello world!';

        $scope.posts = posts.posts;

        $scope.posts.push({
            title: $scope.title,
            link: $scope.link,
            upvotes: 0,
            comments: [
              { author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0 },
              { author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0 }
            ]
        });

        $scope.addPost = function () {

            if (!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
                 posts.create({
                    title: $scope.title,
                    link: $scope.link,
                });
            $scope.title = '';
            $scope.link = '';
        };

        $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
            posts.upvote(post);
        };
}]);
```

In the above controller, if the `addPost` function is replaced with the one that was used in the tutorial before the factory create method was introduced, then it works fine.

Working code:

```
$scope.addPost = function(){
  if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
  $scope.posts.push({
    title: $scope.title,
    link: $scope.link,
    upvotes: 0
  });
  $scope.title = '';
  $scope.link = '';
};
```

So somehow the factory's posts.create method is causing the issue (although posts.posts is accesible).

Below is **post.js** file which  `o.create` method is causing the current issue

```
angular.module('flapperNews').factory('posts', ['$http',
    function($http){

        var o = {
            posts: []
        };
        return o; 

        o.getAll = function() {
            return $http.get('/posts.json').success(function(data){
                angular.copy(data, o.posts);
            });
        };

        o.create = function(post) {
            console.log("o.create");
            return $http.post('/posts.json', post).success(function(data){
                o.posts.push(data);
            });
        };

        o.upvote = function(post) {
          return $http.put('/posts/' + post.id + '/upvote.json')
            .success(function(data){
              post.upvotes += 1;
            });
        };

        resolve: {
            postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
                return posts.getAll();
            }]
        }

    }
]);
```

**app.js** file

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router', 'templates'])
.config([
  '$stateProvider',
  '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .state('posts', {
        url: '/posts/{id}',
        templateUrl: 'posts/_posts.html',
        controller: 'PostsCtrl'
      })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home')
}]);
```

If someone knows what the underlying issue here, then please give advice. Many Thanks :-)

My rails version 4.0.2 and I'm using Linux Ubuntu 12.04

Some thoughts, if I can't get the factory methods working, then I might put those methods directly in controllers to resolve the issue, hopefully :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You returned the object too soon, the other functions didn't register (since they are function expressions, and not function declarations, they didn't get [hoisted](http://howchoo.com/g/ythlzdq1mzb/understanding-javascript-hoisting)). Move your `return o;` to the end and it will work:

```
app.factory('posts', ['$http',
    function($http){

        var o = {
            posts: []
        };


        o.getAll = function() {
            return $http.get('/posts.json').success(function(data){
                angular.copy(data, o.posts);
            });
        };

        o.create = function(post) {
            alert('In create!');
            console.log("o.create");
            return $http.post('/posts.json', post).success(function(data){
                o.posts.push(data);
            });
        };

        o.upvote = function(post) {
          return $http.put('/posts/' + post.id + '/upvote.json')
            .success(function(data){
              post.upvotes += 1;
            });
        };

        resolve: {
            postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
                return posts.getAll();
            }]
        }
        return o;

    }
])
```

See this working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cptum1as/1/).

Comment: Thanks million :-) for sorting out my problem. Now it works! + I'll definitely read more  about JavaScript hoisting from the link you provided - thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your resolve statement should go in the home state in your app.js. As the tutorial says, "By using the resolve property in this way, we are ensuring that anytime our home state is entered, we will automatically query all posts from our backend before the state actually finishes loading."

App.js:

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router', 'templates'])

.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      resolve: {
        postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
          return posts.getAll();
        }]
      }
    })

  .state('posts', {
      url: '/posts/{id}',
      templateUrl: 'posts/_posts.html',
      controller: 'PostsCtrl'
 })

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);
```